# How does Qt find the corresponding library source files to my included header?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qmake

I wanted to include QGraphicsSvgItem into my project for which I needed to add `QT += svg` to my .pro file (nothing else was changed from the standard generated .pro file). However, after cleaning, rerunning qmake and re-building in different combinations and adding the `QT += svg` to different points in the .pro file, it could never find the header since it was still only searching in C:\Qt\6.3.2\mingw_64\include\QtWidgets instead of C:\Qt\6.3.2\mingw_64\include\QtSvg(& Widgets). So I tried simply putting everthing in the two other folders into QtWidgets. But now it seems Qt can't find the source code since I get

> undefined reference to
> `__imp__ZN16QGraphicsSvgItemC1ERK7QStringP13QGraphicsItem'

It even looks like it's trying to use the library in the makefile:

> MyProject.pro \ 
> C:/Qt/6.3.2/mingw_64/lib/Qt6Svg.prl \ 
> C:/Qt/6.3.2/mingw_64/lib/Qt6Widgets.prl \
>
> ... 
> MyProject.pro:
> C:/Qt/6.3.2/mingw_64/lib/Qt6Svg.prl: 
> C:/Qt/6.3.2/mingw_64/lib/Qt6Widgets.prl:

What am I missing?

Edit: Added .pro file for clarity:

```
QT       += core gui
QT += svg

#DEFINES += QXT_STATIC

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++17

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    attributeviewwidget.cpp \
    connectioncheckwidget.cpp \
    connectpath.cpp \
    dbpu.cpp \
    dbputextdisplay.cpp \
    dbputypes.cpp \
    deleteconnectionaction.cpp \
    inoutputsymbol.cpp \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp \
    mygraphicsview.cpp \
    timetabledbpurect.cpp \
    timetablewidget.cpp

HEADERS += \
    attributeviewwidget.h \
    connectioncheckwidget.h \
    connectpath.h \
    dbpu.h \
    dbputextdisplay.h \
    dbputypes.h \
    deleteconnectionaction.h \
    inoutputsymbol.h \
    mainwindow.h \
    mygraphicsview.h \
    timetabledbpurect.h \
    timetablewidget.h

TRANSLATIONS += \
    Queryplaner_de_DE.ts
CONFIG += lrelease
CONFIG += embed_translations

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Wunused-parameter

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

RESOURCES += \
    resources.qrc
```

Comment: `What am I missing?` - the whole way on how to add a Qt module to your project with qmake. In the documentation you can find  in the header for every class what to do, for example [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpushbutton.html): `qmake: QT += widgets`

Comment: @chehrlic I added `QT += svg` to the .pro file already, as mentioned above. Isn't that the whole way?

Comment: Please post your pro-file and not just some pieces

Comment: @chehrlic Added. I thought it was unnecessary since I haven't changed anything else from what Qt Creator generated

Comment: Ok, are you sure you compile and link with MinGW and not with MSVC - from my pov '__imp__ZN16QGraphicsSvgItemC1ERK7QStringP13QGraphicsItem' is a MSVC symbol, not one generated by MinGW. You can not mix MinGW and MSVC c++ libraries.

Comment: @chehrlic I'm pretty sure since I've never used MSVC or MSVC libraries.

Comment: @chehrlic I've found a way to make my code run: I've removed the svg header files I manually put into include\QTWidgets and included <QtSvgWidgets/QGraphicsSvgItem> instead of <QGraphicsSvgItem> so it can now finde the header itself. 
I then got the same error but in Makefile.Debug:132. In that Makefile only Qt6Svg.a and .prl are used. When I added Qt6SvgWidgets manually it suddenly compiled and showed my svg icons properly! Everytime I clean I have to add everything again though... what is qmake doing?

Answer (score 0):

So it seems -even though it doesn't say so on the svg-related doc site- (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsvg-module.html, especially https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicssvgitem.html) `+=svgwidgets` needed to be added as well. Otherwise Qt only searches in the QtSvg libraries and not QtSvgWidgets.